# ASPX extension not showing when browsing site from VS2013 IDE

Tags: webforms

i have created a web site with VS2013 IDE and my .net framework version is 4.5.

i select default webform template with no authentication and IDE generate project with many code and aspx file.

when i run my code from IDE then aspx extension is not showing. i comment this code in RouteConfig.cs file

```
 //var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings(); 
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent; 
//routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

but still aspx extension is not showing. so tell me what i need to change as a result aspx extension should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing that is enough to remove friendly URLs for me, you do also have to edit your Site.Master etc to change the links from ~/About to ~/About.aspx for example.

Otherwise, check for other URL rewriting as described in Scott Gu's blog: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net